# Django Image processing app ? where should i call the imageprocess function ? in the views or the forms?

Tags: django, image-processing, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to make a django app where i can process Images and show both the preprocessed and the processed,i have the function already ready and tested,how i should implement it? I already developed mini apps where it basically takes a user input without actual processing just showing it in views with some restriction and validations.I have a basic idea how i should construct the model of this app and it looks like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForiegnKey(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preprocessed = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_path)
    processed = models.ImageField(upload_to=another_path)
```

so should i call the process function in the views/forms ?
I think it's in the views but how it should really looks like? should i call the form and save the input from the form if it's valid to the model ? how should i call the image preprocessed to process it and show it in a detail view ?

Comment: do you want user to upload image?

Comment: yes and it will be processed and saved so when he enter a view it shows up.